# Call pure virtual function from child constructor/destructor

Tags: c++

```
class A{
virtual void setEnable(bool enable) = 0;
};

class B : A{
    B() {
        setEnable(true);
    }
    ~B() {
        setEnable(false);
    }
    bool enable_ = false;
    
void setEnable(bool enable) override {
    enable_ = enable;
}
};
```

Am I correct in understanding that the B :: setEnable function will be added to the vtable only after the constructor exits and this is undefined behavior?

Comment: Side note: If you tried this in an `A` constructor you'd get the UB because no derived classes will have been fully initialized yet and `A` doesn't implement the function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Am I correct in understanding that the `B::setEnable` function will be added to the vtable only after the constructor exits and this is undefined behavior?

No. Inside the body of the `A` constructor, the `A` object is fully initialized, but the `B` object is not. The problem with calling a virtual function from a constructor is that it will unintuitively call the method of the same type that the constructor belongs to, without the polymorphic behavior.

Comment: *Inside the body of the constructor the object is fully initialized.* can never be emphasized enough. Perhaps I should even have used ***bold** italics*. Not understanding this leads to a lot of silly bugs and inefficiencies.

Comment: But standard says: "If the virtual function call uses an explicit class member access ([expr.ref]) and the object expression refers to the complete object of x or one of that object's base class subobjects but not x or one of its base class subobjects, the behavior is undefined."

Am I misunderstanding something in this wording?

Comment: @Gogogo The quote starts with "if". It's a special case where this sentence applies.  Check the example in that paragraph.